# c++ string array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string

Can anyone help with how I would declare a string array in my header, set it up in my cpp file then intialize it with values in a for loop. I have to use a C style array so I cannot use vector.

I'm struggling with the best approach at this to use up the least ammount of resources as there are 10,000 ish lines in this text file I'm reading them in from.

Comment: Do you have to read them all into memory?  Can't you read and process a line at a time?

Comment: Can the strings be at least C++ strings or `char*`?

Comment: "I have to use a C style array" too localized for a C++ question.

Comment: If you're using C++, you can use a vector. Otherwise you're not using C++.

Comment: As @DeadMG sort of implied, is this a C question or a C++ question? Or is it contrived-for-homework C++?

Comment: It's an assignment but they want us to use c stlye arrays rather than loading them in using another format or the vector library. I'll post what I have so far but I've only been using c++ for a month or so.

Comment: Voting to reopen as he's posted actual code and improved his question.

Comment: This is still too localized. "C++ but oh wait it's C" is not a general problem.

Comment: @DeadMG: Shocking though it may be for some C++ purists to believe, C++ programmers do sometimes have to talk to C code. Not liking a coding style does not make it "too localized". Granted, I can't say why one would be allowed to use `std::string` and *not* `std::vector`. But that's still not grounds for closing the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not allowed to use `vector`, and **you don't know how how many valid lines the file contains until you're done reading it**, then you have 2 options:

- Simulate `vector`'s behavior by creating an array that doubles in size when it's full
- Make one pass to determine the number of lines in the file. Allocate a fixed size array, and then make another pass to fill the array.

Pick one of these and try it out.  Both have their pros and cons.  The second one is less error-prone to implement.

You could also put the lines in a linked list and then copy them to an array.